# React native animate Modal to show from left to right

Tags: react-native

How can i make my modal show from left to right the way a drawer came out.
I'm using  Modal  from 'react-native', but i also installed react-native-modal module from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/blob/master/README.md.

this is my Code

```
<Modal visible={this.state.modalOpen} animationType='slide' transparent={true} >
          <ShortCut />
        </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

in react-native-modal u can use animationIn and animationOut.Incase of right to left use
slideInRight

```
import React from 'react';

import Modal from 'react-native-modal';


    return (
      <Modal
        testID={'modal'}
        isVisible={this.isVisible()}
        animationIn="slideInLeft"
        animationOut="slideOutRight">
        <ShortCut />
      </Modal>
    );
```

Comment: first thank you for your response, but unfortunately this didn't work. and it seems like my component behaviour doesn't change

Comment: its from my app, its a non-english app

Answer (score 0):

To build on the previous answer from ikmo:

Instead of using the built-in Modal component ("import {Modal} from 'react-native';), you can use the react-native-modal:

Install by running in Terminal:

`npm install react-native-modal`

Then import the newly installed Modal:

`import Modal from 'react-native-modal';`

Now, as ikmo suggested, you can use `animationIn` and `animationOut` props in order to make it work just as you wanted.

Eg:

```
<Modal
  isVisible={modalVisible}
  animationIn="slideInRight"
  animationOut="slideOutRight"
>
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
      >
        <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

(basically just reemphasized the previous answer as, looking at your comments on it, you missed the point that ikmo was talking about the react-native-modal component and not the built-in one)